# Python3 and dev are broken. Cant uninstall, reinstall, or fix, Linux Mint 19 XFCE

Tags: linux, installation, python, linux-mint, packages

**I cant install any programs or packages that require python-3**. It says the **package is broken**, however no matter what I do **I cannot repair it**. Uninstalling it doesnt work, and forcing things dont help either. Here is what I get when trying to repair all packages from synaptic package manager: `E: python3: installed python3 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 4`
This is the log:

```
Setting up python3 (3.6.7-1~18.04) ...
running python rtupdate hooks for python3.6...
E: py3compile:183: cannot create directory /usr/share/hplip/ui5/__pycache__: FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory')
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/aboutdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/aboutdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/aligndialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/aligndialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/cleandialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/cleandialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/colorcaldialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/colorcaldialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/devicesetupdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/devicesetupdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/deviceuricombobox.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/devmgr5.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/devmgr5_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/devmgr_ext.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/fabgrouptable.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/fabnametable.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/fabwindow.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/fabwindow_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/faxsetupdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/faxsetupdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/filetable.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/firmwaredialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/firmwaredialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/infodialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/infodialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/linefeedcaldialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/linefeedcaldialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/loadpapergroupbox.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/makecopiesdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/makecopiesdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/mimetypesdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/mimetypesdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/nodevicesdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/nodevicesdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/plugindiagnose.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/plugindiagnose_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/plugindialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/plugindialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/pluginlicensedialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/pluginlicensedialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/pqdiagdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/pqdiagdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/printdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/printdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/printernamecombobox.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/printsettings_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/printsettingsdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/printsettingsdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/printsettingstoolbox.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/printtestpagedialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/printtestpagedialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/queuesconf.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/readonlyradiobutton.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/sendfaxdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/sendfaxdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/settingsdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/settingsdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/setupdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/setupdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/setupdialog_base5.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/systemtray.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/systrayframe.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/systrayframe_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/ui_utils.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/upgradedialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/upgradedialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/wifisetupdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/wifisetupdialog_base.py'
error running python rtupdate hook hplip-data
dpkg: error processing package python3 (--configure):
 installed python3 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 4
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
A package failed to install.  Trying to recover:
Setting up python3 (3.6.7-1~18.04) ...
running python rtupdate hooks for python3.6...
E: py3compile:183: cannot create directory /usr/share/hplip/ui5/__pycache__: FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory')
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/aboutdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/aboutdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/aligndialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/aligndialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/cleandialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/cleandialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/colorcaldialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/colorcaldialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/devicesetupdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/devicesetupdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/deviceuricombobox.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/devmgr5.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/devmgr5_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/devmgr_ext.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/fabgrouptable.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/fabnametable.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/fabwindow.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/fabwindow_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/faxsetupdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/faxsetupdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/filetable.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/firmwaredialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/firmwaredialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/infodialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/infodialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/linefeedcaldialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/linefeedcaldialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/loadpapergroupbox.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/makecopiesdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/makecopiesdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/mimetypesdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/mimetypesdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/nodevicesdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/nodevicesdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/plugindiagnose.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/plugindiagnose_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/plugindialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/plugindialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/pluginlicensedialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/pluginlicensedialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/pqdiagdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/pqdiagdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/printdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/printdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/printernamecombobox.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/printsettings_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/printsettingsdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/printsettingsdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/printsettingstoolbox.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/printtestpagedialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/printtestpagedialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/queuesconf.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/readonlyradiobutton.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/sendfaxdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/sendfaxdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/settingsdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/settingsdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/setupdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/setupdialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/setupdialog_base5.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/systemtray.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/systrayframe.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/systrayframe_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/ui_utils.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/upgradedialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/upgradedialog_base.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/wifisetupdialog.py'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/hplip/ui5/wifisetupdialog_base.py'
error running python rtupdate hook hplip-data
dpkg: error processing package python3 (--configure):
 installed python3 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 4
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-dev:
 python3-dev depends on python3 (= 3.6.7-1~18.04); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-dev depends on python3-distutils (>= 3.6.7-1~); however:
  Version of python3-distutils on system is 3.6.5-3.

dpkg: error processing package python3-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for gnome-menus:
 gnome-menus depends on python3:any (>= 3.1~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gnome-menus (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3
 python3-dev
 gnome-menus
```

This is the log from purging it:

```
lukaka@Lukaka-Minecraft-PC:~$ sudo apt-get purge python3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apparmor : Depends: python3:any
 apport : Depends: python3 but it is not going to be installed
 apt-clone : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
             Depends: python3 but it is not going to be installed
 aptdaemon : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.2~)
 apturl : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 apturl-common : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 caribou : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 catfish : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 cinnamon-desktop-data : Depends: python3 but it is not going to be installed
 dh-python : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 foomatic-db-compressed-ppds : Depends: python3 but it is not going to be installed
 gconf2 : Depends: python3:any
 gdebi : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 gdebi-core : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 gir1.2-ibus-1.0 : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 gir1.2-xapp-1.0 : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 gnome-menus : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.1~)
 gnome-terminal : Depends: python3 but it is not going to be installed
 gufw : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 hplip : Depends: python3 (< 3.7) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: python3 (>= 3.6~) but it is not going to be installed
 hplip-data : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 lightdm-settings : Depends: python3 but it is not going to be installed
 lsb-release : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.4~)
 menulibre : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 mint-common : Depends: python3 but it is not going to be installed
 mintbackup : Depends: python3 (>= 3) but it is not going to be installed
 mintdesktop : Depends: python3 (>= 3.3) but it is not going to be installed
 mintdrivers : Depends: python3 (>= 3.3) but it is not going to be installed
 mintinstall : Depends: python3 (>= 3.4) but it is not going to be installed
 mintlocale : Depends: python3 but it is not going to be installed
 mintreport : Depends: python3 but it is not going to be installed
 mintsystem : Depends: python3 (>= 3.3) but it is not going to be installed
 mintwelcome : Depends: python3 (>= 3.3) but it is not going to be installed
 mugshot : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 netplan.io : Depends: python3 but it is not going to be installed
 networkd-dispatcher : Depends: python3:any
 nvidia-prime : Depends: python3:any
 onboard : Depends: python3 (< 3.7) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: python3 (>= 3.6~) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 onboard-common : Depends: python3 but it is not going to be installed
 openprinting-ppds : Depends: python3 but it is not going to be installed
 orca : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 printer-driver-foo2zjs-common : Depends: python3 but it is not going to be installed
 printer-driver-m2300w : Depends: python3 but it is not going to be installed
 printer-driver-postscript-hp : Depends: python3 but it is not going to be installed
 printer-driver-ptouch : Depends: python3 but it is not going to be installed
 printer-driver-pxljr : Depends: python3 but it is not going to be installed
 python3-apport : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 python3-apt : Depends: python3 (< 3.7) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: python3 (>= 3.6~) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 python3-aptdaemon : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 python3-brlapi : Depends: python3 (< 3.7) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: python3 (>= 3.6~) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: python3:any (>= 3.2~)
 python3-bs4 : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 python3-cairo : Depends: python3 (< 3.7) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: python3 (>= 3.6~) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 python3-certifi : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.4~)
 python3-chardet : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 python3-commandnotfound : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 python3-configobj : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 python3-crypto : Depends: python3 (< 3.7) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: python3 (>= 3.6~) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 python3-cups : Depends: python3 (< 3.7) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: python3 (>= 3.6~) but it is not going to be installed
 python3-cupshelpers : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 python3-dbus : Depends: python3 (< 3.7) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: python3 (>= 3.6~) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: python3:any (>= 3.4~)
 python3-debian : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 python3-defer : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 python3-dev : Depends: python3 (= 3.6.7-1~18.04) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: python3-distutils (>= 3.6.7-1~) but 3.6.5-3 is to be installed
 python3-distutils : Depends: python3 (>= 3.6.4-1~) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: python3 (< 3.8) but it is not going to be installed
 python3-gdbm : Depends: python3 (>= 3.6.4-1~) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: python3 (< 3.8) but it is not going to be installed
 python3-gi : Depends: python3 (< 3.7) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: python3 (>= 3.6~) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 python3-gi-cairo : Depends: python3 (< 3.7) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: python3 (>= 3.6~) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3~)
 python3-httplib2 : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 python3-icu : Depends: python3 (< 3.7) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: python3 (>= 3.6~) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 python3-idna : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 python3-lib2to3 : Depends: python3 (>= 3.6.4-1~) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: python3 (< 3.8) but it is not going to be installed
 python3-louis : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 python3-mako : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 python3-markupsafe : Depends: python3 (< 3.7) but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: python3 (>= 3.6~) but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 python3-opengl : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 python3-pexpect : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 python3-pil : Depends: python3 (< 3.7) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: python3 (>= 3.6~) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 python3-pip : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.4~)
 python3-pkg-resources : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 python3-problem-report : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 python3-psutil : Depends: python3 (< 3.7) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: python3 (>= 3.6~) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 python3-ptyprocess : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 python3-pyatspi : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 python3-pycurl : Depends: python3 (< 3.7) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: python3 (>= 3.6~) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 python3-pyqt5 : Depends: python3 (< 3.7) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: python3 (>= 3.6~) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 python3-pyqt5.qtx11extras : Depends: python3 (< 3.7) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: python3 (>= 3.6~) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3~)
 python3-reportlab : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 python3-reportlab-accel : Depends: python3 (< 3.7) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: python3 (>= 3.6~) but it is not going to be installed
 python3-requests : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.4~)
 python3-requests-unixsocket : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 python3-setproctitle : Depends: python3 (< 3.7) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: python3 (>= 3.6~) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: python3:any (>= 3.2~)
 python3-simplejson : Depends: python3 (< 3.7) but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: python3 (>= 3.6~) but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 python3-sip : Depends: python3 (< 3.7) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: python3 (>= 3.6~) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 python3-six : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.4~)
 python3-speechd : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 python3-systemd : Depends: python3 (< 3.7) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: python3 (>= 3.6~) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 python3-urllib3 : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 python3-xapp : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 python3-xdg : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 python3-xkit : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 python3-yaml : Depends: python3 (< 3.7) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: python3 (>= 3.6~) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 redshift-gtk : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 rhythmbox-plugins : Depends: python3 (< 3.7) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: python3 (>= 3.6~) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 sessioninstaller : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 slick-greeter : Depends: python3 but it is not going to be installed
 system-config-printer : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 system-config-printer-common : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 system-config-printer-udev : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 ubuntu-drivers-common : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 ubuntu-minimal : Depends: python3 but it is not going to be installed
 ubuntu-system-service : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 ufw : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 vidcutter : Depends: python3 (< 3.7) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: python3 (>= 3.6~) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 virtualbox : Depends: python3 (< 3.7) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: python3 (>= 3.6~) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
 xapps-common : Depends: python3 but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: python3:any
 xed : Depends: python3 but it is not going to be installed
 xviewer-plugins : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

This is the result from running the recommended fix: 
https://github.com/ITCMD/ITCMD-STORAGE/raw/master/result1032323.txt (ran out of characters).

The same thing happens with the following dependencies:
`Python3` `python3-dev` `gnome-menus`. It often says when attempting to install things, that it requires a specific version of python3, and that I have a different version installed, except the two version numbers it gives are the same. Any ideas how to fix?

Comment: "error running python rtupdate hook hplip-data" – maybe running this separately will give you more info on the actual error. But I've been in similar Python situations under Linux and at some point just decided to give up and reinstall the entire system. Do you remember how you got into the situation in the first place?

Comment: No it was working fine before. I’ll try that.

Comment: `lukaka@Lukaka-Minecraft-PC:~$ sudo python rtupdate hook hpilp-data
[sudo] password for lukaka: 
python: can't open file 'rtupdate': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: Hm, perhaps this helps: https://askubuntu.com/a/1056876/17529

Comment: This post fixed my problem: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056077/how-to-install-latest-hplip-on-my-ubuntu-to-support-my-hp-printer-and-or-scanner/1056078#1056078 (which I found off that link) thanks!

Comment: Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to mess around with my HP hplip files.

this tool fixed it all:

**Download:**
`wget https://kent.dl.sourceforge.net/project/hplip/hplip/3.18.12/hplip-3.18.12.run`
([this is the official link from HP if you want that](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/gethplip))

**Run:**
`sh hplip-3.18.12.run`

It had a few errors in there, especially with scandisk, but it worked over all and fixed all my python packages!